# Fit peaks over two different data ranges in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a data set with two primary peaks and then several minor peaks in the background. The two peaks are separate, but close enough where the tail of one of the gaussians would affect the magnitude of the other.

What I'd like to do is to pick two ranges (say at the towards the top of both peaks) where then simultaneously fit gaussians to those peaks without having to fit any of the minor peaks between them.

How would this be possible?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you are working with along with the code you have written to process it?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?